# Add data from html form to a sql database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add data into a database created using phpmyadmin by entering information into a html form but whenever I click on 'submit' it goes to the 'insert.php' form and the error i get is 'no data received' This is my insert.php code. I have literally type out the same code in this website. "http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp" (the Insert Data From a Form Into a Database section". I am using XAMPP as my server. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to create a form in html & set method type in form get or post

Comment: Don’t use tutorials from that website – http://www.w3fools.com/; go look for a _proper_ one. And then try to _understand_ what is done there, look stuff you don’t know about up in the manual – just by typing in the exact same code you won’t learn much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help

Form.html

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    //checking if data has been entered
    if( isset( $_POST['data'] ) && !empty( $_POST['data'] ) )
    {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
    } else {
        header( 'location: form.html' );
        exit();
    }

    //setting up mysql details
    $sql_server = 'localhost';
    $sql_user = 'user';
    $sql_pwd = 'password';
    $sql_db = 'database';

    //connecting to sql database
    $myslqi = new mysqli( $sql_server, $sql_user, $sql_pwd, $sql_db ) or die( $mysqli->error );

    //inserting details into table
    $insert = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO table ( `data` ) VALUE ( '$data' )" );

    //closing mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have set the form action and method.

```
<form action='insert.php' method='POST'>

//HTML inputs here

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check first:

Have insert.php echo all the data you are passing into it via get or post.  I would wager what's happening is an error with the form.  Failing that, run the insert inside php admin manually (there's an sql tab once you're in your database, run your query there to make sure you don't have an sql error).  If that is also fine, then post your html and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
Last name <input type="text" name="last">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

and your file insert.php should look like the one in the link you have (w3schools). Of course, you need to change variables to `name` and `last` and working MySQL connection!