# insert value in mysqli from h1 html

Tags: php, html

I have the file index.php:

```html
    <div id="content">
      <h4> title </h4>
      <h3> subtitle </h3>
      <h4> quiz </h4>
<form action="insert_value_mysqli.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

How can i assign attributes or how can i insert in the table below these texts: title, subtitle and quiz? Or what procedures to use to introduce values in the table?

```html
table:
+----+----------+
| ID |  VALUES  |
+----+----------+
| 1  | title    |
| 2  | subtitle |
| 3  | quiz     |
+----+----------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Start from asking how to create an HTML form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add data from html form to a sql database using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683959/add-data-from-html-form-to-a-sql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with jquery and php :

Jquery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>   

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $("#content h1").html();
        var subtitle = $("#content h2").html();
        var quiz = $("#content h3").html();
        console.log(title);
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert_value_mysqli.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: {title:title, subtitle:subtitle, quiz:quiz}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and values
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data){
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log('failed');
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>title here</h1>
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
    <h3>quiz</h3>
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

`insert_value_mysqli.php` code bellow :

```
<?php
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $subtitle = $_POST['subtitle'];
  $quiz = $_POST['quiz'];
  //now you can use insert query
?>
```

Comment: @ster You are Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use English (my English is not good either) please whenever you are asking a question on public platform. 
what i understand in your question is that you want to enter value that user gives as an input to database. 
Similar question has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683959/add-data-from-html-form-to-a-sql-database-using-php).
Hope this helps :D

Comment: In the future, if you see a similar question, you may want to consider flagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Lexi how do this?

Comment: You should at the bottom of the question (before the answers) see the words `share`, `edit` and `flag`. Click `flag` and then you can select an option such as `duplicate` and paste a link to the question that you think it is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Start by learning how to create html form [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Then after that you can slowly learn php [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Good luck.